# How to add a mouselistener to my button on BlueJ

Tags: button, mouselistener

So I have this button on BlueJ, but it doesn't do anything and I don't know how to make it work. How do I adapt this code so that my button will say something, for example "Hello World!"?

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
    public class testKnop {
    public static void main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton b1 = new JButton();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        b1.setSize(300,300);
        frame.add(b1);
        b1.setSize(400,400);
        b1.setText("Test button");
        b1.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);       
    }
}
```

Thanks allready :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest way is to `implements ActionListener` to your class and then add it to `b1.addActionListener(this);`.